# Summation of infinite series: $\frac{9}{5^2\cdot 2\cdot 1}+\frac{13}{5^3\cdot 3\cdot 2}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

[image: This is the summation I am looking for.]

I found a pattern that (if we start from $n=1$) the numerator is $5\cdot(n+1)$, while the denominator is $5^{(n+1)}\cdot (n+1)\cdot (n)$.

But what do I do ahead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Note that the numerator has the form $4n+5$, and
$$\frac{4n+5}{5^{n+1}(n+1)n}=\frac{1}{5^nn}-\frac{1}{5^{n+1}(n+1)}.$$
Then what is the sum of this series?

Comment: So is the final answer going to be $1/5?$ (because all the terms terms will 'annihilate'?)

Comment: @Harsha G. Yes, that's right!